# Control execution flow for better code design

Tags: c

I'm not sure how exactly to address this problem, I hope you guys can help me.

I'm creating a card game in C (a text-only game that runs on the terminal window) called [truco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truco). It is a best-of-3 game that goes until one team reaches 12 or more points, so we have three tricks (let's call it round) each worth 2 points and the game continues with up to three rounds played until one team reaches 12 points.

When playing truco one can "ask for truco" to raise the stake of the match (I'm calling the best of three tricks a match), and the other player can accept, refuse or raise the stake again (essentially accept and then ask for truco).

I'm currently trying to implement this functionality, but my code is probably not the best design as I am suffering to add the "refuse" option, when a player refuses the truco, the other should be given as the winner (of that match) immediately.

And here comes my question, suppose the user asks for truco on the first trick, and the CPU refuses (the game is just you against the CPU for now) how do I "skip" all other code related to other tricks and set the user as the winner for that match?

I don't know how to design the code to allow this kind of feature, in normal cases two or three tricks should be played, but if some player asks for truco and the other refuses the game should ignore the remaining tricks and all other functionalities relating to it, going to the end of the match, updating the score and start another match.

Below I created a small reproducible code to clarify things (just note that I removed and altered a lot of code to keep it simple):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// variable to store the result of the trick and also the final result of the match
int current_result = 0;

void ask_truco()
{
    printf("asking truco...\ntruco refused\n");
    // game should verify current_result and skip to reset_deck
    current_result = 1;
}

void play_trick()
{
    printf("playing trick\n");

    // simulating that match should be interrupted and finished
    ask_truco();

    // this should be skipped, but not in normal situations
    printf("do something...\n");
}

int check_winner()
{
    printf("checking winner\n");
    // hard-coded CPU wins
    return 2;
}

void reset_deck()
{
    printf("resetting deck\n");
}

int play_match(void)
{
    // asking for truco here, second and third tricks should not be played
    play_trick();

    while (true)
    {
        play_trick(); // while loop helps play second and third trick
        current_result = check_winner();

        // from ask_truco, I should go back here
        if (current_result == 1)
        {
            printf("increasing user score\n");
            break;
        }
        else if (current_result == 2)
        {
            printf("increasing cpu score\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    // resetting deck of cards
    reset_deck();

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    play_match();
}
```

In the actual project, I have a few files and functions, if I just use ifs and flags I will end up with a mess, is there a better way to do this? I was wondering if the event-driven design would help me...

Comment: In the actual project, is `play_trick` `void`?

Comment: "just note that I removed and altered a lot of code to keep it simple" – this is really good to do for Stack Overflow questions! In this case, though, I think you removed too much; there's not enough information left for me to suggest another way of organising the program.

Comment: Re *"How do I skip all other code related to other tricks and set the user as the winner for that match?"* and *"I just use ifs and flags I will end up with a mess"*. By writing a **flow chart**, which could be in pseudocode form, a diagram, or a hybrid (as I do). Expect to have to scrap versions until you've got it. If you are evaluating one trick: make that a function, which can `return` as soon as there is a conclusion.

Comment: @WeatherVane Or use [one little `goto` instead](https://xkcd.com/292/).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 dinosaur food!

Comment: @wizzwizz4 play_trick returns a trick structure, which I use to control the state of each round (who won or if it was a tie who was the one who tied)

The project is in here if you are interested: https://github.com/wejesuss/truco/tree/feat/ask-truco

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry didn't get the last part, you want to encapsulate the `play_trick` function with another function?

Comment: Obviously within the `play_hand` function. But your `play_trick` function doesn't do anything. Your trimmed-down code does not do anything useful, and you are asking us to provide an algorithm to solve the game.

Comment: I removed a lot of stuff that I thought was not directly related to the question, the things I removed I pushed to the `feat/ask-truco` branch on the repository I posted above

Comment: Sorry, you can't expect readers to explore your github repository. Questions should be more focussed than "how do I write my card game?"

Comment: @WemersonJesus So, you're returning values _and_ you have globals? I would suggest not doing that, for starters. Try removing all your globals; a better program control flow will probably fall out. (Failing that, Weather Vane's "make a flowchart" suggestion is a good one.)

Comment: In case you took my `goto` suggestion seriously: in C, you can't `goto` in between functions; it'll corrupt memory, if the compiler even allows you to do it in the first place.

Comment: Well I don't know how to redesign or what strategy I could use to make that functionality possible, I need to play 2-3 tricks normally but skip the remaining (at whatever trick I am), considering I have many functions inside of functions, I don't know how to organize it...

Comment: I will try to redesign the program, maybe recreate everything

Comment: Yes, you need to have a plan. Coding without a plan is just typing. Callable functions are wonderful. Use as many as your plan needs. Then, an enum of the various stages of the game, a simple loop with a switch statement that can analyse and 'transition' to any "next state" works wonders...

Comment: I will think of that, thank you all

Comment: How many players? Your code talks about (CPU, user) but discussion mentions  teams?  There are 3 tricks each worth 2 points.  How does that get you to 12 points?  I would create a struct that records game state and you pass that around.  Make use of return values, for instance, `play_trick()` may want to return the result of that trick.  This means it `ask_truco()` should probably return a result.  Use enums so you can name things (it improves readability over just using ints).

Comment: @AllanWind although it's just two players (computer and user) I used the term teams in the question to describe them, sorry for confusing you, each match is worth 2 points (base stake), but it can be increased by asking for truco (then it will be worth 4 then 8 then 12), when a player wins a match his score will be increased by the current stake, when one of them reaches 12 or more, the game is finished.

As I said earlier, the code above has a lot of alteration, you can read from the repository if you want, I'm already returning a `trick` structure on `play_trick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after reading the comments some of you provided me, especially @Fe2O3 and after strungling with myself a little bit I implemented the approach presented to me and manage to solve the problem. I would like to take the opportunity to explain what I did.

First of all, let me explain what my code was before, in my question above I committed the error (as some of you pointed) to remove *too much* of my code, which prevented you to fully understand what my code was doing.

I will start showing you three files of my project, again some of the things were removed or altered, but this time I think it's pretty concise and still understandable.

1. My types definition

   ```c
   // types.h
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdbool.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <time.h>

   #define TOTAL_CARDS_NUMBER 40
   #define TOTAL_HAND_CARDS_NUMBER 3

   enum suits
   {
       spades = 1, // (♠)
       hearts,     // (♥)
       diamonds,   // (♦)
       clubs       // (♣)
   };

   enum rank
   {
       four = 1,
       five,
       six,
       seven,
       queen,
       jack,
       king,
       ace,
       two,
       three
   };

   enum trumpcards
   {
       facedown = 0,
       fourclubs = 14,
       sevenhearts = 13,
       acespades = 12,
       sevendiamonds = 11
   };

   typedef struct card
   {
       enum suits suit;
       enum rank rank;
       bool available;
       int value;
   } card;

   typedef struct player
   {
       card cards[TOTAL_HAND_CARDS_NUMBER];
       int *player_tentos;
   } player;

   typedef struct player_action
   {
       int choice;
       bool ask_truco;
       bool hide_card;
   } player_action;

   enum round_result
   {
       TIE,
       WIN,
       LOSE
   };

   typedef struct trick
   {
       enum round_result result;
       bool is_tied_by_user;
   } trick;

   /*
   prototypes
   */

   void play_hand(card *cards, player *user, player *cpu);
   void reset_deck(card *cards);
   card ask_cpu_for_card(card *cpu_cards);
   card ask_user_for_card(card *user_cards);
   ```
2. My main file

   ```c
   // truco.c
   #include "./types.h"

   int main(void)
   {
       printf("Truco\n\n");

       card cards[TOTAL_CARDS_NUMBER];
       // prepare deck, generating the cards
       /* set_deck(cards); */

       player user, cpu;
       int user_tentos = 0;
       int cpu_tentos = 0;

       user.player_tentos = &user_tentos;
       cpu.player_tentos = &cpu_tentos;
       while (user_tentos < 12 && cpu_tentos < 12)
       {
           play_hand(cards, &user, &cpu);
       }

       /* show_final_victor(user_tentos, cpu_tentos); */

       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Match related file

   truco is a best-of-three game for each match, and has a lot of matchs played before the game finishes

   ```c
   // match.c
   #include "./types.h"

   void play_hand(card *cards, player *user_ptr, player *cpu_ptr)
   {
       int stake = 2;
       int *user_tentos = (*user_ptr).player_tentos;
       int *cpu_tentos = (*cpu_ptr).player_tentos;

       // distributing cards
       /* draw_cards(cards, user_ptr, cpu_ptr); */

       trick tricks[3];
       int trick = 0;
       enum round_result current_result = TIE;

       while (true)
       {
           tricks[trick] = play_trick(user_ptr, cpu_ptr);
           current_result = check_winner(tricks);

           if (current_result == WIN)
           {
               // user wins
               (*user_tentos) += stake;
               break;
           }
           else if (current_result == LOSE)
           {
               // cpu wins
               (*cpu_tentos) += stake;
               break;
           }
           else if (trick == 2)
           {
               // third trick in case of tie-tie-tie
               break;
           }

           trick++;
       }

       // cards should be made available again here
       reset_deck(cards);
   }

   trick play_trick(player *user_ptr, player *cpu_ptr)
   {
       card *user_cards = (*user_ptr).cards;
       card *cpu_cards = (*cpu_ptr).cards;

       card user_card, cpu_card;
       trick trick;

       // ask players for card, possibily asking truco
       ask_cards_from_players(user_cards, cpu_cards,
                           &user_card, &cpu_card);

       // populate trick structure with result of current round
       /* set_trick_result(user_card, cpu_card, &trick); */

       // visual only - show user played cards and round result
       /* show_played_cards(user_card, cpu_card); */

       return trick;
   }

   void ask_cards_from_players(
       card *user_cards, card *cpu_cards,
       card *user_card, card *cpu_card)
   {
       // ask each player for a card in correct order
       // I removed this part to keep it concise and simple

       // user can possibily ask truco
       *user_card = ask_user_for_card(user_cards);

       // cpu could possibily ask truco
       // but let's focus on the user for now
       *cpu_card = ask_cpu_for_card(cpu_cards);
   }

   card ask_user_for_card(card *user_cards)
   {
       // show user cards
       /* show_player_cards(user_cards); */

       player_action action = {
           .choice = 0,
           .ask_truco = false};

       card card;

       // get user choice, including they called truco or not
       /* get_choice(&action); */

       // get card using choice
       /* card = get_card_from_hand(action.choice); */

       if (action.ask_truco)
       {
           // ask cpu if it accepts truco
           // if so, maybe the cpu wants to call truco (retruco)
           // if retruco, we should ask the user, if they accept truco
           // again the user may call retruco now, and so on
           // otherwise, the player who called truco should be considered the winner
           // if there is a winner in this way, we should set `current_result` accordingly
           // the tentos should be updated and the game should skip to line `43` on `play_hand` function
           // that is, the `reset_deck` function call

           // if truco is just accepted, but retruco is not called
           // the game should continue
           // and stake for this match should be increased
       }

       return card;
   }

   card ask_cpu_for_card(card *cpu_cards)
   {
       // show cpu cards
       /* show_player_cards(cpu_cards); */

       card card;
       // get a random card for cpu
       /* card = get_random_card(cpu_cards); */

       return card;
   }
   ```

That's it, here we have most of the code related to the question, still, some extra things here and there that I kept to maintain everything in context.

As you can see above, my is in case truco is refused. Suppose cpu refuses truco, how do I come back from `ask_user_for_card` to update `user_tentos` in the while loop inside `play_hand` function and immediately go to line 43 and `reset_deck()`, finishing that match?

Of course, I could use a lot of if statements, maybe change the return type of some functions, or even create some new structures*, but I think that you make the code a little messy, remember this is still a reduced and simplified sample.

** To tangent a little, I was wondering if it's considered a bad practice to create structures with the sole purpose to return more than one thing in a function, even though the properties may not be related...*

To solve the problem, the idea @Fe2O3 gave me was a key factor, why not use enums to separate each state of the game and use a loop with a switch to change from one stage to another?

To organize things better I decided to create another file called `state-manager.c` together with its `.h` couple. This file is responsible for managing the state of the match, it would store and update the state of the game.

```c
// state-manager.h
enum states
{
  END_OF_MATCH = -1,
  IDLE,
  CHECK_USER_TURN,
  SET_ASK_PLAYER_CARD,
  ASK_USER_CARD,
  ASK_CPU_CARD,
  SET_TRICK_RESULT,
  SHOW_PLAYED_CARDS,
  CHECK_WINNER,
  UPDATE_WINNER_TENTOS
};

enum calltruco
{
  NO_PLAYER_ASKING_TRUCO,
  USER_ASKING_TRUCO,
  CPU_ASKING_TRUCO
};

typedef struct state
{
  enum states current_state;
  enum states previous_state;
  enum states next_state;
  // which player is asking truco
  enum calltruco current_asking_player;
  // which player has asked truco
  enum calltruco previous_asking_player;
} state;

state get_state();
state update_state(enum states new_state);
state reset_state();
state set_asking_player(enum calltruco new_asking_player);
```

```c
// state-manager.c
#include "./types.h"
#include "./state-manager.h"

/*
  THIS FILE MANAGES THE STATES FOR THE MATCH
  Its purpose is to control the flow of the program
  when playing three tricks of the game (each match worthing 2-base points)
*/

static state match_state = {
    .current_state = IDLE,
    .previous_state = IDLE,
    .next_state = IDLE,
    .current_asking_player = NO_PLAYER_ASKING_TRUCO,
    .previous_asking_player = NO_PLAYER_ASKING_TRUCO};

state get_state()
{
  return match_state;
}

state update_state(enum states new_state)
{
  match_state.previous_state = match_state.current_state;
  match_state.current_state = new_state;

  return match_state;
}

state reset_state()
{
  match_state.current_state = IDLE;
  match_state.previous_state = IDLE;
  match_state.current_asking_player = NO_PLAYER_ASKING_TRUCO;
  match_state.previous_asking_player = NO_PLAYER_ASKING_TRUCO;

  return match_state;
}

state set_asking_player(enum calltruco new_asking_player)
{
  match_state.previous_asking_player = match_state.current_asking_player;
  match_state.current_asking_player = new_asking_player;

  return match_state;
}
```

And in my `match.c` almost everything was changed

```c
// match.c new version
void play_hand(card *cards, player *user_ptr, player *cpu_ptr)
{
  int stake = 2;

  state match_state = get_state();
  trick tricks[3];
  int trick = 0;
  enum round_result current_result = TIE;
  card user_card, cpu_card;

  while (match_state.current_state != END_OF_MATCH)
  {
    switch (match_state.current_state)
    {
    case IDLE:
      printf("IDLE\n");
      // checks and populate the next state
      match_state = idle(match_state, trick);
      update_state(match_state.next_state);
      break;

    case CHECK_USER_TURN:
      printf("CHECK_USER_TURN\n");
      is_user_turn = check_user_turn(tricks[trick - 1]);
      update_state(SET_ASK_PLAYER_CARD);
      break;

    case SET_ASK_PLAYER_CARD:
      printf("SET_ASK_PLAYER_CARD\n");
      update_state((is_user_turn) ? ASK_USER_CARD : ASK_CPU_CARD);
      break;

    case ASK_USER_CARD:
      printf("ASK_USER_CARD\n");
      // now I can just return out of the function it truco is refused
      match_state = ask_user_card(match_state,
                                  user_cards,
                                  &user_card,
                                  &current_result,
                                  &stake);

      // and update the state accordingly
      update_state(match_state.next_state);
      break;

    case ASK_CPU_CARD:
      printf("ASK_CPU_CARD\n");
      // do more stuff...
      break;

    case SET_TRICK_RESULT:
      printf("SET_TRICK_RESULT\n");
      // do more stuff...
      break;

    case SHOW_PLAYED_CARDS:
      printf("SHOW_PLAYED_CARDS\n");
      // do more stuff...
      break;

    case CHECK_WINNER:
      printf("CHECK_WINNER\n");
      // do more stuff...
      break;

    case UPDATE_WINNER_TENTOS:
      printf("UPDATE_WINNER_TENTOS\n");
      // whatever it does, I can go here anytime I want and break out of the loop
      break;

    default:
      printf("default\n");
      update_state(END_OF_MATCH);
      break;
    }

    match_state = get_state();
  }

  reset_state();

  // cards should be made available again here
  reset_deck(cards);
}
```

Again, I naturally just showed related stuff, but I think it is still possible to see the changes, now I have a loop with a switch statement to change from each state of the game to another, I control from where I am to where I will go.

My only concern is, this approach although works great is arguably more complex to read understand and maintain, honestly I'm glad I managed to do this; any other suggestion or comment is appreciated.

Thank you!